# Confusion regarding Apache document root

Tags: javascript, php, apache, virtualhost, document-root

In one of the applications that I am working on for my company, I came across a weird behaviour or maybe it's just my misunderstanding and I hope I can get some clarification.
The application is served by Apache and the root is : **/company/client**. For every page that I visit, for example https://11.11.11.11/index.phtml, it will actually point to the file in the server **/company/client/index.phtml** and so on. In one of the modules of the application, it contains a `move_uploaded_file` php function, and the target directory is /images/example/, when the page is run, the app is trying to go to the absolute server root **/images/example/** instead of **/company/client/images/example/**.

Also the a new windowed opened up by window.open has an img tag having **src='/images/exmaple/'**, this points to the server root instead of **/company/client/images/example/**, is this expected?

Am I missing anything, or is it something to do with Apache configuration?

**Additional info:**

The application is served as a virtual host in conf file, with DocumentRoot "/company/client/".

The page that is executing window.open and php function is used as an Iframe inside /company/client/index.phtml

sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Using the `.phtml` extension is a little irregular to say the least. The convention is `.php`, but exposing that kind of information is usually bad form. The extensions can vanish if you use MultiViews.

Comment: The "web root" defines where to start looking for static assets. A URL of `/images/example.png` will actually be in `/company/client/images/example.png`. Whenever working with file paths internally, keep this in mind.

Comment: PHP paths are relative to the file system and do not know or care about the document root folder. A client side URL like `/test/blabla.phtml` will most definitely not go further up than the document root. You must be mistaken.

Comment: @tadman As far as I understand OP is absolutely aware of that and specifically asking about observed behavior that doesn't seem to match that concept.

Comment: @tadman yes as chris mentioned I am aware of the path for url, and Chris you are correct, it was my mistake, I was meant to say other things but got carried away.

Comment: @ChrisG does the img src tag work the same way as php path? see my edit in the post thanks!

Comment: No, the image src attribute exists inside the browser and contains a (relative) URL i.e. is dependent on the document root. Again, `<img src="/images/example.png">` cannot possibly display an image outside your document root folder. The leading slash means the absolute URL is composed by adding the relative URL to the hostname, so this will load the image from `document_root/images/example.png` Being able to access files anywhere on the hard drive would be an enormous security hole; the chances of you having discovered that in apache are zero.

Comment: @ChrisG thx for the clarification, it must be my mistake somewhere in my understanding, I'll investigate and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help from the everyone especially Chris G, the problem was that the code is using a GET variable incorrectly, as a result the image name isn't passed. And I got confused because someone made a mistake in the code by moving image relative to the root folder which is incorrect. That made me think that PHP is also treating path like the client side which is a mistake. I'm guessing I can conclude that the web server document root only applies to everything client side, like the url, JS, HTML?

Comment: The client should have absolutely no idea what the web root is. You don't want to leak this information inadvertently, either, via error messages and such.

Comment: Basically yes: a script or image src, a stylesheet or link href, or a form action, all these end up being full URLs that are requested from the server. Apache appends the path to the document root and either sends back the file or runs the PHP script. If it does the latter however, the PHP script is basically a program running on the server; it has a location on the hard drive and full access to it.